# Is it possible to fix hard bricked device?

Tags: rom-flashing

I'm working in electronic repair store as technician and I started 4-5 years ago but something really bothers me .

Why we can't fix hard bricked devices ? Like device's hardware completely fine . Is there some kind of device for that problem ?

I have 5-10 devices just laying dead because of hard brick because some amateur tried flash a ROM without any experience

Also I don't know if here is correct place to ask this question , I'm basically trying to flash a android ROM but if it isn't right place for it I can delete my question and please if you're not %100 sure don't write "you can't fix hard bricked devices" , I heard&said that for a long time

Comment: A bricked device is usually an example of the chicken-egg-problem. Unless you have direct hardware access to the flash memory chips you need at least a minimal software stack for accessing the flash chips. If your on-device software stack is completely flashed to hell how do you get write access to the flash? Additionally security measures like closed bootloader makes it even more harder as you can't just flash/run any software you want.

Comment: If the software is available for your device, you can use a JTAG programmer, although later devices tend to support this less and less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a softbricked device, critical partitions like a recovery partition is usually preserved which helps to easily recover from the condition, but in a hardbricked device all the software interfaces that provide access to the hardware are unavailable, that means there is no method for you to communicate with the hardware. As Robert has rightly said, you need to physically access the hardware in order to flash a software, which in case of integrated hardware is very difficult. To circumvent a hardbrick situation, Snapdragons have an Emergency Download Mode (EDL).

Comment: So basically not possible ? Unless you have specific hardware for every device ? I don't think they made universal device for it but if they did I can buy it

Comment: It is next to impossible to recover from a hardbrick if you do not have a dedicated recovery method (like EDL). Sometimes, even the manufacturers are not able to recover from a hardbrick. Acejavelin has suggested a valid method called JTAG debugging but Qualcomm/MTK mobile chips rarely support it.  Now, as MTK and Qualcomm chips are most commonly found ones, it is possible to recover from a hardbrick, even though the chances are slim. You may make use of QPST, QXDM tools by Qualcomm, and MTK Vcom tools by Mediatek.